# radDateTimePicker best way to get and format the date value?

Tags: c#, telerik, format, datetimepicker

I need get the value of `DateTimePicker` component (like visual studio native `DateTimePicker` component, and basically the same thing) and turn it into a variable `DateTime` to execute a query in the `Mysql` database, the best way to play this value to see this format:

```
'2015-08-07'

 yyyy-mm-dd
```

Can anyone tell me how can I do this?

Comment: have you assigned datepicker to a textbox?

Comment: use as a parameter in the method to perform the query in SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private DateTime InitialDate;
private DateTime EndDate;


this.dataInicial = new DateTime(radDateTimePickerInitialDate.Value.Year, radDateTimePickerInitialDate.Value.Month, radDateTimePickerInitialDate.Value.Day);
this.dataFinal   = new DateTime(radDateTimePickerEndDate.Value.Year, radDateTimePickerEndDate.Value.Month, radDateTimePickerEndDate.Value.Day);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Web Forms implementation...

```
protected void btnMyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsValid) return; // Handle rdpMyDateTimePicker not having a selected date by using a RequiredFieldValidator control
    if (rdpMyDateTimePicker.SelectedDate == null) return; // Proper form validation should always prevent this being null

    var formattedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rdpMyDateTimePicker.SelectedDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

    // Now insert the formattedDate string as a parameter into your database query
}
```